# Data Table R - Aggregation

Tags: r

I want to aggregate data in R but in a very generic way with the right hand side (columns) stored in a object as string. Below is the example expression

```
aggregate(PATTERN_ID ~ Year + Week), data, length)
```

So in my case, right side which is "Year + Week" is going to be changing as in required and i want to pass it as a string stored in variable. I tried using evaluation strategy but does not give the required output. Below is what i have tried:

```
exp_aggregate_by  = 'Year + Week'
aggregate(PATTERN_ID ~ eval.quoted(parse(text = exp_aggregate_by)), data, length)
```

Any input from the people will be much appreciated. Through data table is also fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a formula with `paste` and it should work

```
data(mtcars)
grp <- 'cyl + gear'
aggregate(formula(paste('mpg ~', grp)), mtcars, length)
```

For the OP's dataset,

```
aggregate(formula(paste('PATTERN_ID ~', exp_aggregate_by)), data, length)
```

Answer (score 2):

An answer with data.table. I'm also including the answer using formula in aggregate for completeness.

```
vars <- c('Year', 'Week')

# with aggregate
form <- formula(paste('PATTERN_ID', paste(vars, collapse = '+'), sep = '~'))
aggregate(form, data, length)

# with data.table
setDT(data)
data[, length(PATTERN_ID), by = vars]
```